# Scala pattern matching down the class hierarchy

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible to have Scala keep pattern matching down the class hierarchy after successfully matched a parent class? For example, I'm expecting the following code to print 1 and 2, but after matching `S` against `T`, Scala won't keep going and matching the next case, so the next case will never be reachable.

```
class T
class S extends T

new S match {
  case _: T => println(1)
  case _: S => println(2)
}
```

Comment: So you want it to print *BOTH* 1 and 2?

Answer (score 4):

The first matching case is always selected. Just swap the order and test for the subtype S before testing for the parent class T. Or you can have a nested pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

The closest i can think of would look like this ,

```
class T
class S extends T

new S match {
 case c@ (_: T  | _: S ) => println(1)
}
```

This way you could check if `new S` is of either of the types.

Answer (score 1):

Scala pattern matching does not support fall-throughs. I actually asked this exact question a while ago ([Scala pattern matching - match multiple successful cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560257/scala-pattern-matching-match-multiple-successful-cases))

You would need to do it independently for every possible case.

If your actual use case is different (i.e. you have dozens of these conditions and you need to execute them sequentially in an elegant way) - I would possibly opt to use a different method and not pattern matching at all.

Possibly, what I would do (to maintain a functional paradigm) would be something like this:

```
class T
class S extends T

val myTestedVal = new S

((x:T) => ( 
    (x match { case z:S => (()=>println(2)) case _ => } ) ::
    (x match { case z:T => (()=>println(1)) case _ => } ) ::
    // Add other cases here
     Nil)) (myTestedVal).collect { case i:(()=>Unit) => i }.foreach(z => z())
```

The above sample code would print both 2 and 1 for `S`, and just 1 for `T`. What it does, is it basically runs the list of conditions, creating a list of functions to run based on the successful conditions, and then executes them in the `foreach` (which could also be modified to be a `map` if you need the functions to return meaningful values).

### Note

The above method is definitely overkill for the OP's simple use-case. However, if you have multiple conditions that you want to execute in a "rule-engine" style, the above method is more elegant and "functional" than having a long chain of "if" statements.

*Disclaimer: I am somewhat new to Scala and FP myself.*

Comment: `isInstanceOf` isn't really "maintaining function paradigm". This is an awfully overcomplicated way to print out two characters :D

Comment: @Dima I meant the general way of doing it, not the actual `if` statements (which I am assuming were just an example and his use case is larger than this, with 10+ conditions).

Comment: @Dima Updated to use pattern matching instead of `isInstanceOf`. But, the point of my post was to show the way of "accumulating functions and then executing them", not the actual `isInstanceOf` tests, which were just an example.

Comment: the question is why "accumulate functions" rather than just run them.

Comment: @Dima What do you mean? The point is to run a series of tests against an object, and then run them all sequentially in order to simulate a case fallthrough. So let's say you have an object coming in over the wire that you deserialize; you build a simple execution list based on various tests that you run against it, and then run that list. I'm sure there are other ways to do it, just don't see why this way is particularly "wrong".

Comment: what I mean is, you have some conditions to check, so why not just check them instead of turning each into a function, throwing actions into a list, creating another function, to return the list, and then calling it and going through the list to execute them? Doesn't it look like an overkill to you? What's the upside?

Comment: also note, that your updated code will throw a `MatchError` if the parameter type is not `S`.

Comment: @Dima None in practice; this was just an academic example. And yes, it does look like overkill, but I don't think his original use case was to output "2 1" either. The practical way is to use a chain of `if` statements or multiple `match` statements, but that's not really "functional". Something like my answer might make sense if you have 30 conditions. But, I actually don't know what the proper, functional way of doing something like that is; in my opinion, they should extend the `match` statement to be able to support multiple matches. (Also, example code fixed; thanks)

Comment: "functional" doesn't mean "turning everything into a function" ;) Pattern matching in particular, is a perfectly "functional" construct.

Comment: @Dima Didn't say it was... But as far as I understand it, functional means 1) immutable and 2) tendency toward a pipelined (monadic) expression. Pattern matching is perfectly functional, yes, but Scala's pattern matching cannot be used as intended for OP's use case.

Comment: @Dima I did, but it looks a bit hacky to me (not saying that my way is great either; it's not). For example, how would you make the conditions dynamically-driven? Let's say that you have the matched object coming in though the wire, and you want to "score" it based on different matching rules (potentially having these rules come from anywhere, not necessarily hard-coded) - and then execute these rules sequentially? (I admit that I'm going on a huge assumption here, and this is probably not what the OP wanted; however, this is what I one day wanted, and that was the route I took)

Comment: I don't think it hurts to have more ways of doing things in one answer, instead of less :) You haven't pointed out what's particularly wrong with my answer; the way that I intended it, it is like a miniature rule engine which can be easily extended. If that's not what the OP wanted, there are other answers, but someone else might be looking for this way (again, I was looking for this way, when I asked the exact same question 8 months ago).

Comment: that was the very question this branch of discussion started with: why would I want these conditions "dynamically driven"??? There is nothing in the question to suggest that was a requirement.

Comment: @Dima Yes, and it is not dynamically driven in my example. But can be easily changed to be that way (or another way), if needed. It's just a starting point showing a theory; that's what programming examples are for...

Comment: And I don't need to "point out what's particularly wrong with your answer" to your satisfaction, this is not a debate or a competition. I am just saying what I don't like about it, take it or leave it

Comment: Well, you downvoted, so yes - you kind of do. Otherwise, you're just being a dick

Comment: I downvoted it because I don't think it is a good solution for the problem at hand. I explained why I think it's not a good solution, probably, in more detail, than I should have. I (kinda) agree with you I should explain why I downvoted it (and I did), I don't agree I have to convince _you_ in particular that those reasons are sound ;)

Comment: @Dima I get it, and don't disagree. Just wanted to understand myself (because that is a way that I came up with, and I am new to FP & Scala, so if there is something fundamentally wrong with it - I'd definitely want to know myself). But yes, not trying to have a debate or argue, was just trying to understand :)

Comment: the question is not at all about checking conditions that are "dynamically driven". Why don't you also show how to create a parser that would read the cnoditions  from a text file or (better!) a socket while you are at it?

Comment: Yes, I think, there is something fundamentally wrong with it: you just need to check if you variable is of a particular type .. writing a function, that will create and return a list of anonymous functions, that will then need to be executed in order to get the answer to the question is "fundamentally wrong" in my book

Comment: I guess we are of different opinions and will have to agree to disagree. People other than the OP will come to this question with similar problems, and some of them could want something more extensible; I don't see how my way is even remotely worse than your first method of doing it (nested matches). What if the matching chain he wants is not sequential? Is he going to have to repeat code in each branch? Anyway, it's not worth arguing over; I get your point, but I disagree.

Comment: "People other than the OP will come to this question" that's exactly why I feel it is important to make my point known here. ;)

Comment: @Dima Ok. Clarification note added to answer. 2 people already upvoted, so obviously *someone* did find it helpful.

Comment: doesn't help, I am afraid: I don't think it is either "more elegant" or "more functional" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Think of pattern matching as a sequence of `if-else if - else -if ...` statements. You cannot execute more than one branch. The way around it is, depending on the complexity of your selectors, either nesting:

```
new S match {
   case t: T => println(1)
       t match {
         case _: S => println(2)
       }
}
```

or duplicating some of the actions in multiple branches:

```
new S match {
   case _: S => println(2); println(1)
   case _: T => println(1)
}
```

Or else using partial functions, which may be an overkill for your case, but just for completeness:

```
Option(new S).map { 
  case s:S => println(2); s
  case s => s
}.collect { 
  case _:T => println(1) 
}
```